# Why is FOR IN code cycling through the last in the array when repeated (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a sample of the code that i wrote below:

```
animals = ['rat', 'fish', 'fool', 'cat', 'lion']
for animals in animals:
    print('i am a ' + animals)

print('\n \n')

for animals in animals:
    print('i am a ' + animals)

print('\n \n')

for animals in animals:
    print('i am a ' + animals)

print('\n \n')

for animals in animals:
    print('i am a ' + animals)
```

The problem is: the first "print" command prints correctly but the next "for, in, print" command cycles through each letter of "lion" in the array and the subsequent print commands just repeat "n" for the last letter in "lion"...

Is there something wrong with the code i've written? Anyone know what's going on? Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `for animal in animals: print(animal)` Try this.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your iterating variable is the same as the name of your list.

At the end of your first for loop, "animals" becomes "lion".

Hence, the second loop runs through "lion". And similarly, at the end of the second loop the variable becomes "n".

Answer (score 0):

every time you go into a for loop you are reassigning the variable "animals". So at the end of the first loop animals is not your list anymore, but the string "lion". At the end of second loop animals is asigned to the string "n" and stays like this in the last loop. It would be allways the same if you right the code as follows:

```
animals = ['rat', 'fish', 'fool', 'cat', 'lion']
for animal in animals:
    print('i am a ' + animal)

print('\n \n')

for animal in animals:
    print('i am a ' + animal)

print('\n \n')

for animal in animals:
    print('i am a ' + animal)

print('\n \n')

for animal in animals:
    print('i am a ' + animal)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your iterator has the same name as the list, so you should maybe rename it to `animal`:

```
animals = ['rat', 'fish', 'fool', 'cat', 'lion']
for animal in animals:
    print('i am a ' + animal)

print('\n \n')

for animal in animals:
    print('i am a ' + animal)

print('\n \n')

for animal in animals:
    print('i am a ' + animal)

print('\n \n')

for animal in animals:
    print('i am a ' + animal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are using `for animals in animals:` for all the for loops which means `lion` will be stored in `animals` at the end of the first for loop and it will be fed to the second one and so on. 
You have to use `for animal in animals:`

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same variable name for list and the indexing variable, the last of this gets assigned to `animals` and next loop runs on `lion` as the value of `animals` and not the list that you wanted. You should instead do

`for animal in animals:`

> Is there something wrong with the code i've written?

A lot of things actually.
I believe that you want to print the name of each animal on a new line thus trying the for loop. Now the point of loop is to reduce the code redundancy. However, you have written for loop four times which is something that defeats the purpose of looping.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
for animals in animals:
    print(animals)
```

is actually the equivalent of:

```
 for i in range(len(animals)):
     animals = animals[i]
     print(animals)
```

as you can see, this rebinds the name `animals`, so after this loop `animals` points to the last item in the original list (in your case the string `"lion"`). Since strings are iterable, the second for loop iterates over the individual letters in `animals` (which now points to the string `"lion"`), so after the second loop, `animals` now points to the last letter in `"lion"`, which is `"n"`. Subsequent loops now all iterate over the (one-letter) string `"n"`.